# jQuery UI addClass method not animating visibility?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

One of the helpful features of jQuery UI is its hijacking of the jQuery `addClass` method, adding animation support by including a second 'duration' parameter, like so:

```
$('div').addClass('someclass', 1000);
```

For incoming CSS properties like `color`, `background-color`, `width`, `height` etc, this all works fine.

But transitions like `visibility:hidden` -> `visibility:visible` and `display:none` -> `display:block` do not gracefully fade in as I would expect them to. They simply wait until the duration is complete and then appear when the class is finally added.

I'm sure, in the past, I've seen graceful transitions with these CSS types in jQuery UI. Does anybody else know if this is/has been possible?

I'm aware of the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods, along with the `animate` method, but I'm looking to give more precedence to my stylesheets, instead of having to overload my scripts with style animation logic.

I know CSS3 transitions will do it just as well, but I'm looking for a better-supported approach.

Comment: Why not slideUp() or fadeIn() ?

Comment: Thought someone might recommend that. As you were adding your comment I was adding another paragraph to my question. Second to last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` and `visibility` do not have transitionable states - they are either on (you can see an element) or off (you can't see the element).

If you want it to fade in, then you have to use opacity.

Comment: I'm aware that they are rendered either on/off by the engine. That doesn't mean that jQuery UI shouldn't consider the possibility of using a fade on detection of such a CSS change. It already handles the task of sniffing-out the incoming class's properties, and then applying inline styles during the transition process. There's no reason they couldn't leverage this functionality on the detection of a `display` or `visibility` change. Having said that, I will accept your answer that it is not currently possible to do this with jQuery UI's `addClass` method.